# jScrollPane is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using jQuery jscrollpane plugin http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ to set some feature in my application. The question is it doesn't show the jscrollpane at all.

HTML:

```
<div class="boxcontent" id="dummy">
    <p>
        abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzkdksflajsdfkljasdlfkjas
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dummy {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.horizontal-only {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#dummy").jScrollPane();
```

I included all the requirements shown in jScrollPane download section. But it is not displaying anything.

Could anyone tell me the mistake?

thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding more than one element under `div#dummy`?

Comment: @Eliran Malka yes I tried but still it doesnt show any jscrollpane. Just a plain text

Comment: @EliranMalka http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/Rq7b2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the plugin initiation is called before the element is attached to the DOM. to fix this wrap your initiation with DOM ready callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dummy").jScrollPane();
});
```

here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq7b2/1/), as edited based on the original fiddle.